# Does a subclass inherit the private properties of its parent class, in java?

Tags: java, inheritance

The book I am reading says I cant, but my program proves otherwise. For example the code below compiles well, even though i try to access the private properties of the parent class. Then I can freely print them. Can anyone tell me if the book is wrong, or am I doing something wrong?

```
class Asset
{
    private int Id;
    private String type;

    public int getId()
    {
        return Id;
    }
    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public void setId(int Id)
    {
        this.Id=Id;
    }
    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type=type;
    }
    public void printDescription()
    {
        System.out.println("Asset Id: "+Id);
        System.out.println("Asst type: "+ type);
    } 
}

class BankAccount extends Asset
{
    private String bankName;
    private int accountNumber;
    private float balance;
    public String getBankName()
    {
        return bankName;
    }
    public int getAccountNumber()
    {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public float getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBankName(String bankName)
    {
        this.bankName=bankName;
    }
    public void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber)
    {
        this.accountNumber=accountNumber;
    }
    public void setBalance(float balance)
    {
        this.balance=balance;
    }


    public void printDescriptionnn()
    {
        System.out.println("The Bank name is: "+ bankName);
        System.out.println("Account number: "+ accountNumber);
        System.out.println("Your balance is: "+ balance);
    }
}

public class AssetTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        BankAccount llogari= new BankAccount();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sinput= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type the ID of your asset: ");
        llogari.setId(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Type the type of your asset: ");
        llogari.setType(sinput.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Give the bank name: ");
        llogari.setBankName(sinput.nextLine());
        System.out.print("Type the Account Number: ");
        llogari.setAccountNumber(input.nextInt());
        System.out.print("Type your balance: ");
        llogari.setBalance(input.nextFloat());
        llogari.printDescription();
        llogari.printDescriptionnn();
    }
}`
```

Comment: private members are never inherited

Answer (score 3):

You can access them through `public` or `protected` getters but you can't access the `private` properties directly. In your example, you're using the `public` setters to modify the property. You can access them through `public` method !

So to answer you question, `private` members are **not** inherited by subclasses. Alternatively, you can have `protected` members that are inherited by subclasses.

#### EDIT

From [Java Language Specificiation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.2)

> Members of a class that are declared private are not inherited by subclasses of that class.
>
> Only members of a class that are declared protected or public are inherited by subclasses declared in a package other than the one in which the class is declared.

Comment: Yeah but i thought that "not-inheriting" makes it impossible for the subclass to access these properties. Accesing them with getters and setters, means that they are actually inherited, just not directly accessed. Im confused by the word inherit, explain me please.

Comment: @suspicious They are not inherited they are visible to the subclass.

Comment: well of course they are inherited. I am accessing them using an instance of the subclass

Comment: @suspicious You are accessing them through the `public` setters (which are inherited by the subclass).

Comment: Private members of your superclass ARE inherited; you just can't access them directly. For example, a `JLabel` inherits the `background` property of `Component`, but since it is private, JLabel instances can access it only via the getterand setter.

Comment: @FredK No they **are not**. See my edit. I already explained why the subclass can access them.

Comment: The JLS uses the term *inherited* in a manner thats almost inuitively *misunderstood*. What most people will expect when talking about inheritance is the existance of the item in question, when using that intepretation its impossible to *not inherit* something in OO (you can't remove anything from your super types). But the JLS uses it specifically in reference to whats inherited into the *namespace* of a subtype, which essentially describes *visibility*. @suspicious

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not directly modifying the parent class's elements. You're calling public functions that modify the private elements, which is completely valid.

Answer (score 1):

A subclass does not have direct access to the `private` members of a super class. It only has direct access to the `public` and `protected` members.

In this context, direct access means: `super.member`

If the super class implements protected or public accessor or mutator methods, then you may be able to indirectly access them. Indirect access would look something like: `super.getMember()` or `super.doSomething()`.

Answer (score 0):

Any subclass does not have permission to direct access of the private members of a super class. It can access to the public and protected members.